# RecyclerView could not be instantiated in the newest ver. of Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I try to use RecyclerView in my app. 
I have the following problem:

*"The following classes could not be instantiated:
 android.support.v7.widget.recyclerview
TIP: Use View.IsInEditMode()"*

I read a lot of articles on this forum which helped a lot of users but for me those methods don't work in my program.

I updated my Android Studio to the newest version: Beta 4 (Canary) and Sdk version also but I am not sure if my build.grade was updated properly.

I think that it could be caused by some unstable version of this Android Studio but I'm not sure. A lot of people resolved this by update of software.

When I set on API23 it compiled but didn't work on my API 21 (Lollipop).

Could somebody help me to resolve this problem?

My **build.grade**:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.karol.material_test"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

}
```

**Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3D5AFE"
    tools:context="com.example.karol.material_test.NavigationDrawerFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerDrawerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#BBDEFB"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView

        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:src="@drawable/karol"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Please show the full error message with some context where you are seeing it.  Also show your layout where you added the recyclerview.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I added this layout and error. Do you see sth wrong in my code?

Comment: @war_Hero I've done it many times but It doesn't improve my program.

Comment: try removing the existing import and do it again

Comment: @war_Hero What does it mean? Should I remove this layout or project? Sorry but I don't understand your statement.

Comment: in your gradle file remove the existing recyclerview import

Comment: @war_Hero I did it and 'Invalidate Cache/Restart' too but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to paste the below code in your app leve build gridle file above dependencies

```
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                def requested = details.requested
                if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                    if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                        details.useVersion '26.1.0'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        android {
            packagingOptions {
                exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
                exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
                exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
                exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
                exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
            }
        }

    dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'

}

        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

    }
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please also explain what is wrong with the OP's code and how this code is going to help. Copy-pasting the code will not help anyone to learn and become better!